# loading bar, checkoff sheet, asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, loading

Is there any way to when you click submit on a form, as each method call within the form submit post method completes, a check box checks off to show the user progress of the next page being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I think the best you could do is to disable the form and make ajax calls to each "progress" action that you want the user to be aware of. Each ajax call could then update the page with whatever indicators you want. The resulting flow would look something like this:

- User clicks on fake "submit" button.
- Page is disabled
- Ajax call to "progress" action method 1 - Update page with indicator
- Ajax call to "progress" action method 2 - Update page with indicator
- Ajax call to load new page.
- Display new page to user